# Combining a variables file with a template in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I want to combine a file with style-specific variables with a general template using the variables, so I only have to define the css once in the template,but do have different styled css files in the end.

Example:

Lets say I have 2 colors.scss files with color variables.

colors1.scss:

```
$background: blue;
$foreground: white;
```

colors2.scss:

```
$background: lightgreen;
$foreground: black;
```

and a template file with the css:

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: $foreground;
    background-color: $background;
}
```

So how do I need to write my style1.scss and style2.scss, to combine the variables with the template, so it'll result in the following css files.

style1.css:

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: blue;
    background-color: white;
}
```

style2.css:

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: lightgreen;
    background-color: black;
}
```

I know I can do it 1-1 with for style1.scss:

```
@import 'colors1.scss';
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: $foreground;
    background-color: $background;
}
```

But I really do not want to repeat the content of the template file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly it was easier than I thought.

You just have to import the variable and template files and they're automatically combined.

So basically my files look as followed:

style1.scss:

```
@import 'colors1.scss';
@import 'template.scss';
```

style2.scss:

```
@import 'colors2.scss';
@import 'template.scss';
```

And that's all there's to it.